# Refresh View data in View->ViewModel upon event in view

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms, valueconverter

Simplified, We have a Xamarin.Forms App with:

- A view with a Label
- A viewmodel that has a DateTime property.

They are bound with a valueconverter that convertes the DateTime into local text, like "Tomorrow at 14.46".

The problem is, that when midnight is reached, the data is not updated to show "Today at 14.46" as the datasource has not changed.

Ofcourse, at midnight, we could throw a PropertyChanged event in the viewmodel, but we would prefer not to, as the data really haven't changed, - only the representation of it.

Therefore, i would like to know if there is a way to force a view to refresh the  the data it is bound to?

Note: we need this both in common label views and listview cells.

Comment: If you are using some kind of binding/mvvm pattern, I guess you could use an app wide pub/sub system that fires when a timer has 'passed'. Most mvvm frameworks have a messaging system in place for this. Only tricky thing to get going is keeping track of the correct time passing. Would think each time app launches gets foreground keep track of a timer till midnight?

Comment: Yup. We made a appwide timer to notify views.

The question is simply how to force an update of the data for views in question, as they use databinding and we do not control them.

Comment: Weird, bound items with databinding and INotifyPropertyChanged should 'auto update' when their underlying data is changed... so there is actually nothing to force in a correct scenario. You should however be sure you are changing the data of the actual item that is inside your list view of course.

Comment: No, the data WILL update when we update the underlying data.

The problem is that we have a specific datetime that is se to some time tomorrow, This property is translated by our valueconverter to the text "Tomorrow".

When we reach tomorrow, the text will, however, still say "Tomorrow" as the underlying data has not changed.

Therefore we need to prod the view to have it update again so it will be translated to "Today" this time.

In Essence: Data has not changed, but the views perception of the data has changed, hence an update i needed.

Comment: In Xamarin, a valueconverter is btw. a static class set on a binding, translating the data that comes through. In our case from datatime to a datenoun - like Today/Tomorrow/Yesterday

Comment: Yeah get your point... So the timer sends a global mvvm message. The viewModel registers to it. When it happens, it says to the data in the list view to refresh itself. Refresh method should be written in an interface the data model can implement. If should then re throw the notify property changed for all properties you need to refresh

Comment: I would just raise PropertyChanged on the entire view model, it only happens once per day, seems like a lot of extra work to try to avoid it

Comment: The view model itself has no changed data... so nothing will change on the ui. You need to rethrow the property change for that one you need to view an UI change. Because your viewcell has binding to that property level...